# pythonでwatchdogのイベントが二回発火してる原因が分からない

Tags: python

watchdogでフォルダを監視して変更があった場合printするものなんですが
なぜかon_modifiedの中身が二回表示されます。
以下がソースと結果です。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

import os
import time

target_dir = r"対象フォルダのパス"

class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        filepath = event.src_path
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        print('%sを変更しました' % filename)

if __name__ in '__main__':
    while 1:
        event_handler = ChangeHandler()
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, target_dir, recursive=True)
        observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

このファイルを実行して、対象フォルダにある例えばtest.txtを編集して保存を1度すると実行中の窓に

```
test.txtを変更しました
test.txtを変更しました
```

と、二度printされてしまいます。
どうすればちゃんと編集された回数分の1回だけ出るようになるのでしょうか？
ちなみに下記のようなon_createdは期待通りの動きで

```
class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        filepath = event.src_path
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        print('%sができました' % filename)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        filepath = event.src_path
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        print('%sを変更しました' % filename)
```

これで新しいテキストファイルを作ると1度だけ～ができました、と出ます。
でもこの状態で例えばtest.txtをCtrl+D&Dで同じフォルダ内にコピーすると

```
test - コピー.txtができました
test - コピー.txtを変更しました
test - コピー.txtを変更しました
```

やはりmodifiedのほうは二回分こう出力されます。
ご指導宜しくお願い致します。

追記:以下環境です。
OS Windows7 64bit
Python 3.7.1
Watchdog 0.9.0
以上です、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 参考 (関連するかもしれない watchdog の issue です): ["Modifed event triggered twice"](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/93) ／ ["Large file raises multiple modified events"](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/309) 後者の issue では「タイムアウトを使え」と言われてもいます。

Comment: 前者は全く同じ現象を言っているように見えますね。結構前からある問題のようで、ある意味安心しました。私の場合、回答にあったハッシュ比較で対処出来ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 原因？

実装に問題はなさそうなので、編集して保存する際のエディタの挙動なのでは、という気がします。

## 対策

ファイルの変更が通知されるタイミングでハッシュを確認し、変更があれば通知する、という実装に変えてみてはいかがでしょうか。以下サンプルです

```
import hashlib
hashes = {}

def on_modified(self, event):
    filepath = event.src_path
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        checksum = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
    if filename not in hashes or (hashes[filename] != checksum):
        hashes[filename] = checksum
        print('%sを変更しました' % filename)
    else:
        # ハッシュが既存のものと変更していない
        pass
```

Comment: ハッシュ比較とても参考になりました。私はこれで解決出来ましたが、複数のエディタで検証しても同じ結果だったのと、pythonからwriteで追記したようなテキストファイルでも起きたのでエディタの問題ではなさそうということコメントしておきます。

Answer (score 2):

PollingObserverを使用することで解決できました。

```
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
```

```
observer = PollingObserver()
```